# Can I set the default order on the Table class on cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.x there was a property `$order` in Models. So I used this property to order my data globally. So for example assuming that I need to show a select box with countries on a view in my `Country` model used to add the line:

```
$order = 'Country.country DESC';
```

and then when I fetched the countries from any controller the data where ordered by the country name and not by the `id` or any other field. This was very helpful specially for the select boxes. On CakePHP 3.x I can't seem to find any similar reference at the documentation.

Is there anything that I can do to have my data sorted globally when I fetch them and not use the order option in each find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add your beloved property back and use the [beforeFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind) callback in the Table object to add the value from the property to the query.

Or just [create a custom finder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods):

```
public function findOrdered(Query $query, $options) {
    return $query->order([
        $this->alias() . '.name' => 'ASC'
    ]);
}
```

And use it

```
$this->find('list')->find('ordered')->all();
```

Or create an ordered list find that returns the whole ordered list.

```
public function findOrderedList(Query $query, $options) {
    return $this->findList($query, $options)
    ->order([
        $this->alias() . '.name' => 'ASC'
    ]);
}
```

Or overload the findList() method directly and call the parent.

Or if your `find()` gets called via a relationship, you can [set the default order for the relationship](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) by using the `sort` option.

```
$this->hasMany('AuditLogs', [
    'sort' => [
        'AuditLogs.timestamp' => 'desc',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I'd recommend `$this->aliasField('name')` instead of the concatenation with `->alias()`

Comment: @burzum is there an example of the beforeFind option you have stated?

Answer (score 10):

In CakePHP 3.x, if you want so set default order for every query of a model, then you can place following code in your table:

```
public function beforeFind ($event, $query, $options, $primary) 
{
    $order = $query->clause('order');
    if ($order === null || !count($order)) {
        $query->order( [$this->alias() . '.sort_field_name' => 'sort_order'] );
    }
}
```

If any `order` set from outside, it skip the default order. Otherwise, it will always sort by `sort_field_name` according `sort_order`.

Answer (score 4):

You can override findAll method in your table class.

```
public function findAll(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->order(['Country.country' => 'DESC']);
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that! Will be very GLOBALLY.

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP3.x:

If you would like to sort the data in your model for every query related to this model, you can simple order the query in the model file via beforeFind:

```
public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, $options, $primary) {

    $query->order(['Model.field' => 'ASC']);
    return $query;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the official docs, see [cakephp book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html), you can add a public variable to the controller object in order to set the default sort order:

```
class InvoicesController extends AppController
{
    public $paginate = [
        'order' => [
                'Invoices.id' => 'desc'
        ]
    ];

....
```