# Set default order to CakePHP 3.x model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In CakePHP 2.x it was possible to set an `orderBy` value in the Model as a default order for each query on that table.

In 3.x there is no mention of this in the docs and my attempts at using a reasonable guess for the variable or method name to achieve this haven't worked.

Anybody know if this is still possible?

Comment: Do you want to sort your associative data from model ? May you provide cakephp 2.x example ?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713463/can-i-set-the-order-on-the-table-class-on-cakephp3

Answer (score 4):

There is no 3.x equivalent.

If you really want this, the cleanest solution would be to attach a behavior which listens for beforeFind, and adds an order if there isn't already an order defined. However, expect edge case problems. You're probably better off putting the order in your find calls where you need them - also easier to read/understand.

Comment: https://github.com/UseMuffin/Orderly

Answer (score 0):

did you try this
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table

```
 $query = $model->find('all', [
        'order' => ['Model.created' => 'DESC']
    ]);
```

Comment: he need a default order. Not to order in every query.